# How to build and run a default libgdx game using Intellij IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am new to Intellij IDEA and libgdx, I have worked on android studio before(It is build on Intellij) so its rather similar.

When I try to build the default libgdx android project it fails with the following error:

```
    Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1573)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:782)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1314)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:991)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1063)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:954)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:787)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:308)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What I did :

**1st. Generated the project using the Libgdx Project Generator :**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2. Opened the project in IntelliJ IDEA Community edition 2008.1** 
[image]

The project structure :

[image]

**I also changed the android mudule settings's Module SDK to Android API 25 :**
[image]

**I then Add Build and debug config for the app :**
[image]

Now when I use the config to run my app I get the error that I specified in the beginning of this post...

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was to update my Intellij IDEA IDE to the latest build and this fixed it, I think it was something they fixed, some compatibility issue between android sdk and libgdx and Intellij.

After the Intellij IDEA it also asked if I want to upgrade the android SDK and tools so I also updated the SDK.

I opened  Intellij IDEA and selected Help > Check for updates, and once updated it worked.